# Why this remove empty paragraphs from the_content does not works?

Tags: filters

I simply want to prevent the creation of empty paragraphs in my WordPress post.

```
function removepar($content) {
    $content = str_replace("<p></p>","",$content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'removepar');
```

I want to know that why this does not work?

### Note

I have found that I can solve this using `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' )`, but my question is: **Why** my first filter isn't working?

Comment: Maybe the priority can be set with a higher priority, if <p></p> are added after your filter by another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because:

- Maybe your filter is running to early as Benoti said in his comments, your filter callback may run before the empty paragraphs are added.
- Maybe you are dealing with something different than am empty `<p></p>`, think `<br>`, `&nbsp;`...

#### Solution 1:

Disable `autop` (remove it's filter).

#### Solution 2:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_244389');
function wpse_244389($content) {
    $pattern = '#<p>(\s|&nbsp;|</?\s?br\s?/?>)*</?p>#';
    $content = preg_replace( $pattern, '', $content );
    return $content;
}
```

---

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261024/358906